# Specify that a package should be installed without optional dependencies within package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

I've written a chat bot for Discord which utilises the [`discord.io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.io) library. While this library provides support for voice-related automation, the installation of those features can be prevented by using the `--no-optional` switch, which saves a lot of bandwidth and time.

```
npm install discord.io --save --no-optional
```

So far so good, but whether I use that option or not, there's no distinction in `package.json` between the version installed with the optional dependencies and the one without, therefore when someone goes on to deploy my bot they will download and install all the unnecessary voice-related modules which I do not make use of.

Is there any kind of solution that would result in said package being installed without optional dependencies when `npm install` is ran in the project folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not currently seem to be possible, as reported in [npm issue #14185](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14185). You can subscribe to that bug report to track progress (if any) on this matter.